Uniswap transaction programatically
I am trying to submit a Uniswap transaction without using the Uniswap interface.
I know that I can auto-sign the transaction using my private key programmatically, however I want something different:
Let's say my wallet is connected to Uniswap from Device A. I want to programmatically build a Uniswap transaction (a swap for example) and submit it to Uniswap, either from Device A, or from another Device B. Then I want Uniswap to send me a transaction request on Device A which I manually approve on Device A on the wallet interface.
So for short, I want to send a transaction programmatically on a dApp but approve it manually.
Is this possible?

Yes, this is possible! To initiate a Uniswap transaction programmatically while approving it manually, follow these steps:
Build the Transaction Programmatically:
Use a JavaScript library like ethers.js or web3.js to construct the transaction. Instead of signing it with your private key, you leave the transaction unsigned. You can then send the transaction request to your wallet using eth_sendTransaction. This will trigger a prompt in your wallet for manual approval.
Use WalletConnect for Cross-Device Interaction:
If your wallet is connected to the dApp on Device A, but you’re initiating the transaction from Device B, you can use WalletConnect to link your wallet on Device A with the dApp on Device B.
Approve the Transaction Manually:
Once the transaction request is sent to Device A, you’ll receive a prompt in your wallet. You can review the details and approve the transaction directly through your wallet interface.
